# Box.com pdf file should not force download instead of open in the browser

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, box

I am using Ruby on rails with boxr gem to integrate box api, and I have to implement a capability where the pdf file should default-open the browser when a user tries to download a pdf file.

Boxr gem provide a method call `download_url`, which forces the browser to download file instead of open in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [embed_url method from the Boxr gem](https://github.com/cburnette/boxr/blob/c35eafcd44474e853d0f3cbe108e7e4385afa1d8/lib/boxr/files.rb#L29) to generate a file preview link. This method takes a Box file id as the parameter and returns back a file preview link. You can preview the file by accessing the link directly or embedding the link into an iFrame.

Comment: Thanks Murtza for your response, I have to implement the same behavior as pdf file hosted in s3, It opens default in browse using pdf.js viewer. Is there a way to acomplish the same behavior? I have gone through this post https://www.dropbox.com/en/help/201. Please help me if this will work with boxr gem.